# float with 3 digits after the point precision

Tags: c, floating-point

How can i can calaulate this in c? :

```
float x = 5;
float y = 4.999

float z = x-y; // 0.001000
```

Now i want `z` to be exactly 3 digits after the point, so that `z` will be = 0.001.
I don't need to **print** `z`, i just need to initialize it with 0.001.

Comment: @dandan78 i saw that before and its only about printing..

Comment: @user3729959 Please read the answer of the linked question. They are not about printing, they are about representation of values in type float.

Comment: there's no way to do that unless you're using a decimal float type

Answer (score 0):

Use the integer datatype and transform all numbers to a multiply of 1000

```
int x = 5000
int y = 4999

int z = x-y // 1
```